# Replace values of list knowing its index and value in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this 3 lists on a Pandas DF:

```
            flat_values                          indexes                  tmp_values
[20, None, None, None, None, 30, 40]           [1, 2, 3, 4]            [40, 30, 10, 10]
```

What I want to do is to get a new field on my DF with a list consisting of the flat_values list and the tmp_values inserted at the position reflected in the indexes list numbers. So that:

```
               flat_values                          indexes                  tmp_values         new_values 
    [20, None, None, None, None, 30, 40]           [1, 2, 3, 4]            [40, 30, 10, 10]    [20, 40, 30, 10, 10, 30, 40]
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean with index position? Both `20` for `flat_values` and `40` for `tmp_values` are position 0.

Comment: Sorry, I mean each number inside the "indexes" list

Comment: So do you mind to restate your question?

Comment: Done. I mean, for example, value 40 of tmp_values in position 1 (first value of indexes list) of flat_values list. Indexes and tmp_values lists always have the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html),

```py
def replace_val(row):
    l = row['flat_values'].copy()

    for i, m in zip(row['indexes'], row['tmp_values']):
        l[i] = m

    return l

df['new_values'] = df.apply(replace_val, axis=1)
```

Here is example,

```
a = [20, None, None, None, None, 30, 40]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = [40, 30, 10, 10]

d = [20, None, None, 30, 40]
e = [1, 2]
f = [100, 120]

df = pd.DataFrame({'flat_values': [a, d], 'indexes': [b, e], 'tmp_values': [c, f]})

def replace_val(row):
    l = row['flat_values'].copy()

    for i, m in zip(row['indexes'], row['tmp_values']):
        l[i] = m

    return l

df['new_values'] = df.apply(replace_val, axis=1)
print(df)

                            flat_values       indexes        tmp_values  \
0  [20, None, None, None, None, 30, 40]  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [40, 30, 10, 10]
1              [20, None, None, 30, 40]        [1, 2]        [100, 120]

                     new_values
0  [20, 40, 30, 10, 10, 30, 40]
1        [20, 100, 120, 30, 40]
```

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I added `copy()` to the function because it also changes the values of `flat_values`. Maybe you want to change it. @FranG91